# Injecting webpack chunks to twig files

Tags: symfony, webpack, twig

I am creating a traditional website (not a single page application) using php/twig/webpack tools. Almost every site has its own entry scripts.  There are also `vendor` and `common` js files.

How can I inject entry chunks *with hash* (to handle browser cache) in my twig files? Those are stored in `templates` folder and should stay there (not go to `public` folder since they are used by PHP). How can I inject script tags to twig files?

This is my twig general layout file:

```
{% block html %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <base href="/">
        <title>
            {% block title %}{% endblock %}
        </title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block scripts %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

And twig for example contact page:

```
{% extends "layout/bootstrap.twig" %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script src="js/entry-contact.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Contact form</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Extraction

As said in the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/), file hashes can be extracted from compilation stats.

```
module.exports = {
  /*...*/
  plugins: [
    function() {
      this.plugin("done", function(stats) {
        require("fs").writeFileSync(
          "stats.json", 
          JSON.stringify(stats.toJson())
        );
      });
    }
  ]
};
```

But it's easier to use one of the plug-ins: [webpack-manifest-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin) or [assets-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assets-webpack-plugin). For example, the `WebpackManifestPlugin` creates a simple JSON file `manifest.json` with bundles mapping to actual file names:

```
{
  "main.js": "main.155567618f4367cd1cb8.js",
  "vendor.js": "vendor.c2330c22cd2decb5da5a.js"
}
```

Now you need to read it and change the paths in the templates.

### Injection

For example, we can create a simple [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html):

```
use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_SimpleFilter;

class WebpackAssetsExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    private $manifest;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // ONLY FOR EXAMPLE! Code is intentionally simplified.
        // In real world you should not parse this JSON in production.
        // Do it at the container building step (in bundle extensions, 
        // compiler passes, etc) or at the cache warming.

        $jsonContents   = file_get_contents('manifest.json');
        $this->manifest = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('webpack_asset', function (string $name): string {
                return $this->manifest[$name];
            }),
        ];
    }
}
```

And apply this filter in your template:

```
<script src="{{ 'vendor.js'|webpack_asset }}"></script>
```

Comment: It does work - many thanks. One issue - in Twig v2 use `new Twig_Filter()`. Thanks again